# How to mark all outgoing changesets as drafts in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

I need to rebase all outgoing changesets, and for that I need to mark them as drafts. Is there a shortcut command to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind. It is:

```
hg phase -d -f "outgoing()"
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer, you know. (And you should.)

Comment: @alexis, thanks for reminder. SO enforces 3 day limit if you didn't tick the option when asking, so after 3 days I just forgot about it.